# Does OpenCV blobFromImage preserve the aspect ratio of the input image?

Tags: opencv, deep-learning

I wonder if the `cv::blobFromImage()` preserves the aspect ratio of the input image when it applies a resize or it stretches the image to the target size.

The documentation says "If *crop* is false, direct resize **without** cropping **and** preserving aspect ratio is performed". The word "**and**" makes the sentence a bit vague raising the question if "**without**" applies to the "preserving aspect ratio".

Comment: a resize to a target size without cropping that guarantees the to preserve the aspect ratio isn't possible, afaik. So probably it means without cropping and without preserving the aspect ratio. But no guarantee from me here.

Comment: @Micka: Thanks for your answer. Can't the preservation of the aspect ratio be possible with zero padding for example?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it **does not** preserve the aspect ratio:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/9e1b1e5389237c2b9f6c7b9d7715d9836c0a5de1/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp#L139-L150

So, the image will be stretched if the AR of your target size is different than the input image AR. This needs to be considered as the features representing an object may change dramatically with this kind of stretches.